# How to prevent a specific React setState call from triggering a mutually dependent specific useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am building a fairly complex search form with a few preset configurations for common searches.

The current set of filters are stored in a state variable `filters`. This object is set whenever a field in the form is modified. When a preset is selected from a drop down, the filters are reset to that preset with this function:

```
function set_preset(preset: string) {
   setCurrentPreset(preset);
   if (preset) {
       setFilters(FILTER_PRESETS[preset]);
   }
}
```

However, to prevent confusion, when the user modifies the form from the preset, I would like the preset value to be reset to "Custom" in the drop down:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentPreset('');
    }, [filters]);
```

As is likely obvious, this simple solution does not function well, as `set_preset` itself sets the filters, and the new filters will trigger the use effect, causing the displayed preset to reset to "Custom" again.

I would, essentially, like some way for the useeffect call to be triggered whenever filters are updated, *except* in the case that they are updated as part of a preset selection.

I know there are a few somewhat hacky ways I could attempt to solve this, such as by using an exterior boolean flag to keep track of when a preset is being set, but it feels like there must be a better way of resolving this.

Comment: It looks like you should set the current preset state on the input event on the form.

Comment: `such as by using an exterior boolean flag to keep track of when a preset is being set` honestly this doesn't seem bad to me. I get why you feel like it's not the cleanest option but it's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **Unmitigated** it would be a better idea to not use the useEffect for resetting the `currentPreset`, and use the onChange function for the filters to call setCurrentPreset to "Custom".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to do is expand your `filter` to have a `isPreset: boolean` value that you can check on. Then your code will look like:

```
FILTER_PRESETS = {
    "optionA": {
        isPreset: true
        // Other values
    }
    // Other presets
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!filters.isPreset){
        setCurrentPreset('');
    }
}, [filters]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to no use `useEffect` to sync some state when another state changes. It is not what it is meant for. `useEffect` is for synchronizing React state with something *outside* of React, like `localStorage` for example.

Instead, you should think more in terms of **events**. In the case is the event is *"when the user modifies the form from the preset"*. Reset the state in the event handler for this interaction.

```
function onChangeForm(newFilter) {
  setFilter(newFilter);
  setPreset('')
}
```

```
function set_preset(preset: string) {
   setCurrentPreset(preset);
   if (preset) {
       setFilters(FILTER_PRESETS[preset]);
   }
}
```

I recommmend reading [Separating Events from Effects](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects) and [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) in the React docs.

A sidenote: consider if `preset` really needs to be state variable. I can't tell from this example (I suppose it's shortened for brevity) but if `preset` is only used witin the `set_preset` function, then it need not be in state.